# Pine tree in java with for loop

Tags: java, for-loop

I wrote a pinetree drawer in java. First it asks for how tall the tree and after that, asks for how many times draw it under each other and at the end it draws the tree's trunk. If the first input is <= 0 it need to stop the whole program and print a message. If the first input is good, but the second input is also <= 0 then stop the program. What is the order to make it operate? Thanks in advance!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int height;
    int stars;
    int level;
    System.out.println("Fenyőfarajzoló program.");
    System.out.print("Kérem a magasságot: ");
    height = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Kérem a szintek számát: ");
    level = sc.nextInt();
    int szelesseg = height - 1;
    if (height <= 0) {
        System.out.println("A magasság csak pozitív lehet.");
    } else if (level <= 0) {
        System.out.println("A szintek száma csak pozitív lehet.");
    } else {
        for (int h = 0; h < level; h++) {
            stars = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
                for (int j = szelesseg; j > i; j--) {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
                for (int k = 0; k < stars; k++) {
                    System.out.print("*");
                }
                stars += 2;
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
    for (int talp = 1; talp <= 3; talp++) {
        System.out.println("   ***");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello may be this can help?  throw an exception to tell that you have insert negative values

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int height;
    int stars;
    int level;
    System.out.println("Fenyőfarajzoló program.");
    System.out.print("Kérem a magasságot: ");
    height = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Kérem a szintek számát: ");
    level = sc.nextInt();
    int szelesseg = height - 1;
    if (height <= 0) {
        System.out.println("A magasság csak pozitív lehet.");
        throw new Exception("height is negative");
    }
    if (level <= 0) {
        System.out.println("A szintek száma csak pozitív lehet.");
        throw new Exception("level is negative");
    }

        for (int h = 0; h < level; h++) {
            stars = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < height; i++){
                for (int j = szelesseg; j>i; j-- )
                {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
                for (int k = 0; k < stars; k++){
                    System.out.print("*");
                }
                stars += 2;
                System.out.println();
            }
        }

    for (int talp = 1; talp <= 3; talp++) {
        System.out.println("   ***");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, with this code if you insert a negative value for high or level it will throw exception and stop running your code

Comment: put this immidiatly after   height = sc.nextInt();  this code  if (height <= 0) {
            System.out.println("A magasság csak pozitív lehet.");
            throw new Exception("height is negative");
        }

Comment: int a;
int b;
System.out.print("Give first number)
a = sc.nextInt();
if ( a <= 0 )
System.out.println("First number must positve and above zero);
System.out.print("Second number")
b = sc.nextInt();

If you try this and give -1 for a, the program write what I want but not ends, it asks for next input. I want to avoid this! By the way I cannot use throws exception in this lesson.

Comment: the way I cannot use throws exception in this lesson : System.exit(1)

Comment: I don't tried your solution becase I find another one. When I using 2 scanner after each other and want to stop the program I use return in the end of if.
Like this:
a = sc.nextInt();
if (a < 0)
System.out.print("Negative number error")
return;
b = sc.nextInt();
if (b > 100)
System.out.print("Greater then 100")
return;
Hope it will help you too when needed!